# How to change the index,without giving wrong output?

Tags: python

So im trying to change the index and output the values as numbers.

this is my code:

```
import datetime 

year = int(input('Enter the year (4 digits):\n'))
month = int(input('Enter the month (1-12)')

DayL = ['Mon','Tues','Wednes','Thurs','Fri','Satur','Sun']
date = DayL[datetime.date(year,month,1).weekday()] + 'day'


print(date)
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter the year (4 digits):
> 2020
Enter the month (1 - 12):
> 1
Wednesday
```

Im trying to get the output as a index, and it should start at Sunday (Sunday = 0), but still give the correct answer. How do i go about this ?

The output i want:

```
Enter the year (4 digits):
> 2020
Enter the month (1 - 12):
> 1
3
```

Comment: only use `date = datetime.date(year,month,1).weekday()`

Comment: why Wednesday is `4` ??

Comment: it was a mistake @lenik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no reason to use `DayL`.

The `date.weekday` function already gives you the numeric weekday using Monday=0.

To map that to a Sunday=0 system, just add 1 mod 7:

```
weekday = (datetime.date(year,month,1).weekday() + 1) % 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
>>> (datetime.datetime( 2020, 1, 1).weekday() + 1) % 7
3
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it.